# Pass parameters between screens in React Native (Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to save value which i get from initialParams, but when I pass bettwen differernt screen this value is beginning.

I know that initialParams just initializing value, but I also used navigation.setParams, and according documenation "method lets you update the params of a screen." Ok. But when I go to  other screen and come back, this value starts at the beginning. The sum up, can I save this update value, that It doesn't change when I pass between screen?

How correct is it to transfer values ​​in this way, and how else can it be done if you have a deep structure of data transfer between components (screens)?

For example code for better understanding

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function HomeScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { itemId } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
      <Button
        title="Update param"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.setParams({
            itemId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
          })
        }
      />
      <Button
        title="Other"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate("Other")
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function OtherScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Home"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate("Home")
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          initialParams={{ itemId: 42 }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Other"
          component={OtherScreen}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [goBack](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#goback) instead of `navigate("Home")`.

> The goBack method lets us go back to the previous screen in the navigator.